# Adding JavaScript just to one node

Tags: javascript

I have added `scripts[] = js/add_property.js` to my `.info` file which works perfectly.

That loads the JavaScript for every page though, so how do you do it so that it only loads for the `.tpl` that it is used in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add the Javascript to a single node, you might also implement `hook_node_view`:

```
<?php
function my_module_node_view($node, $viewmode, $langcode)
{
  if ($node->nid == MY_NODE_ID) {
    $node->content['#attached']['js'][] = array
    (
      'type' => 'file',
      'data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . 'js/add_property.js',
    );
  }
}
?>
```

(Solution adapted from https://www.drupal.org/node/1993228).

Answer (score 1):

Within your theme's template.php, you could use [theme_preprocess_node()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) to distinguish between the types of nodes you like to add your JS to. For the desired type, you can use [drupal_add_js()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7):

```
/**
 * Implements theme_preprocess_node().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if ($node->bundle == 'mytype') {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/js/my-js-file.js');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)

> Adds a JavaScript file, setting, or inline code to the page.

Comment: Thanks I will try node_view in a minute. I had done a google before I asked and it came up with so many ways I ended up confused as to which one to try

Comment: It should have been  'data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/js/add_property.js',
    ); oops there was a missing / but that worked - thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add js to a specific node JS injector works well

https://www.drupal.org/project/js_injector

Now I'm not sure how to set it to work on different templates....